# An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time in .net 4.5

Tags: wcf, asynchronous, .net-4.5

I am trying to call an async method from a WCF service, within a project that targets .net 4.5 and am getting the annoying "An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time" error.
When i create another copy of my app that targets .net 4.0 it works. No error message.

What can that be? Any ideas on how i can fix this?

The async calls are made using Something.DoAsync() and OnCompleted event pattern.

**UPDATE:**

The exact error is:
"An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time. Asynchronous operations may only be started within an asynchronous handler or module or during certain events in the Page lifecycle. If this exception occurred while executing a Page, ensure that the Page is marked <%@ Page Async="true" %>."

My code look something like this:

```
m_Service.LoginCompleted += m_Service_LoginCompleted;
try
 {
    m_Service.LoginAsync(ToByteMesIn(loPar), key.Id);
 }
 catch (Exception exc)
 {
    SendNotification(exc.Message);
 }
```

The error happens when the Login4Aynch method is called.
Showing the exception.

Please bear in mind this only happens when my project is compiled targeting .NET .4.5, the code works fine when targeting .NET 4.0

The m_service is a WCF service : "net.tcp://some.domain.com/something:"

**MORE INFO:**
This is run as a web app, and the WCF server targets .NET 4.5

Comment: I think you need to add more information to get a good answer. Adding code and stack trance might be a good starting point...

Comment: I have added a some info, is that better?

Comment: You are calling a WCF service right? What kind of a application are you calling it from? Web, Console...? What framework does the WCF target?

Comment: I am running a web application. WCF targets .net 4.5